# Error while writing hive table with partition

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyspark, orc

I am trying from PySpark to write a DF to hive:

```
> new_hub_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- ClientId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- HUB_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Version: long (nullable = true)

> new_hub_df.show(2)
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|ClientId|              HUB_ID|            publicID|Version|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|    OPNF|49eff2084ecea86e9...|54102364-6251-4bd...|      1|
|    OPNF|bab2e3fae1183ea69...|1f98cca0-316e-4ed...|      1|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
only showing top 2 rows

> new_hub_df.write.saveAsTable("sb_party_hub_dev.party_hub", mode='overwrite', format="orc", partitionBy='ClientId')
```

I can see my table in Hive, but the schema is incorrect:

```
party_hub

    col (array<string>)
```

and the select returns an error:

```
> select * from party_Hub
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: adl://home/hive/warehouse/sb_party_hub_dev.db/party_hub/ClientId=OPNF/part-r-00003-a82a83a9-da1a-41af-97d0-f449bf0e1e69.snappy.orc not a SequenceFile
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Could you please add ddl. I deleted the post.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a temp table and save it as ORC.  Add partitioned by as necessary.

```
new_hub_df.registerTempTable("newhub")
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE mytbl STORED AS ORC AS select * from newhub")
```